# Компиляция проекта под Android: не выбирается стандарт

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Имеется настроенный проект, который компилируется и запускается на Linux, так же я его собираю на Android но во время компиляции поулчаю ошибки:

`Ошибка: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode`

Эта ошибка связана с тем, что в 98 стандарте С++ нельзя объявить перемменую в цикле.

```
for (int i = 0; /* <- так нельзя */ ...)...
```

Решается эта проблема установкой стандарта 99 или 11 и выше.

В .pro файле проект установлен стандарт С++14 `(CONFIG += C++14)` менял его на 11 и 99 - не помогает.

В проекте так же есть подмодули, пробовал так же выставлять в подмодулях (`.pri` файлах) но результат тот же.

Очень странно то, что при компиляции на Linux отих ошибок нет и он запускается но при сборке на Android возникают эти ошибки.

- `Linux: Debian 6.3.0`
- `gcc version 6.3.0`
- `Android NDK Versoin r17b`
- `Android SDK Version 26.1.1`

Comment: Вы запутались в стандартах. Стандарты С и С++ - разные вещи. С89 (= С90), С99, С11 - это С. А С++98, С++11, С++14, С++17 - это С++. В С++ эта фича была даже в С++98. Скорее всего у вас код компилируется как С (не С++), под стандарт С90.

Comment: Какая-то странная комбинация из бессмысленного вопроса и бессмысленного ответа, при этом почему-то отмеченного, как "принятый". Текст ошибки, как правильно замечено, говорит о том, что компилируется С код. Смена стандарта С++ тут ничего исправить не сможет.

Answer (score 4):

QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG = -std=gnu99

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -std=gnu99